# Why declare function's type?

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this has been asked, but seriously can't find anything, so would also appreciate on how to search for this stuff.

So my question: what is the point of declaring the function's type in general? E.g. here 'as double'

```
Function myFunction(ByVal j As Integer) As Double
    Return 3.87 * j
End Function
```

For a normal variable it has tons of benefits, like less memory, easier to see typos, but why here?

Edit: so, it's good because we can avoid errors, like it giving back a different type of values than expected.

Comment: Refer to [Cpearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx). "This page describes practices you should embrace regarding variable declaration. While adopting these practices can lead to more typing, following them makes code run faster, and makes the code easier to debug and maintain."

Comment: I am voting to close this as off-topic for being primarily opinion-based. My opinion is that it a good thing to declare your return types because it increases the likelihood that the compiler will complain when you are doing something that really doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree with @JohnColeman. Declaring return type creates a contract between you and procedure so that you could be sure you wouldn't get some bogus data.

Comment: These are good answers! So you want it to throw an error, if it's NOT double in this case, is that correct? Is there any other reason?

Answer (score 1):

Functions RETURN something. That type is the type of the return.

In your function:

```
Function myFunction(ByVal j As Integer) As Double
    Return 3.87 * j
End Function
```

You are returning a decimal, so type `Double` make sense.

If you don't return anything, then you can declare it as a `Sub`.

And, for clarification, your function would throw a compile error. Unlike other languages, in VBA to return, we set the function name's value to the thing we want to return:

```
Function myFunction(ByVal j As Integer) As Double
    myFunction=3.87 * j
End Function
```

Now we can call this function to get the `Double` value that it creates:

```
Sub testSub()
    msgbox("This is the result of the function: " & myFunction(10))
End Sub
```

Which would launch a message box saying "This is the result of the function: 38.7"

Comment: This says *what* the return type means, but it doesn't address the actual question which is *why* declare it at all (rather than leaving the return type implicitly `Variant`).

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't mark a comment the answer, let me quote:
@John Coleman
My opinion is that it a good thing to declare your return types because it increases the likelihood that the compiler will complain when you are doing something that really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Excel VBA is different from other programming languages in that it centers around a particular application: Excel.

Functions are useful in Excel VBA primarily because they can be typed directly into a cell on a sheet by an end user.  User defined functions provide near infinite flexibility.  The value the user defined function prints to Excel is formatted based on the function's type--and in a program which is about data visualization, formatting is a huge part.

For example, try putting these four functions into a blank worksheet module:

```
Function myInt(x, y) As Integer
myInt = x / y
End Function

Function myDouble(x, y) As Double
myDouble = x / y
End Function

Function myString(x, y) As String
myString = x / y
End Function

Function myVariant(x, y)
myVariant = x / y
End Function
```

Next, enter each of these functions into a different cell in the workbook.  Use x=1 and y=2.

```
myInt produces "=0"
myDouble produces "=0.5"
myString produces "'0"
myVariant produces "=0.5"
```

If you're okay with Excel deciding how to format your result, that's your choice, but specifying the type offers an entire new level of control.  For example, by simply declaring a function an integer, you can avoid having to devote a line of code to rounding.  By declaring a function to be a string, you can avoid several lines of formatting code trying to get a number to be saved as text instead.

Comment: Could I get a comment from my downvoter?  I'd like to know what you didn't like about my post.